# Problem with rest-assured tests from onlyfullstack repository

Tags: java, rest-assured

I tried to run tests from repository:
https://github.com/onlyfullstack/rest-assured-tutorial.git
but I received such error during any test execution:

```
...\rest-assured-tutorial\src\test\java\onlyfullstack\authorization\OAuth2AuthorizationTest.java:30:17
java: cannot access io.restassured.common.mapper.TypeRef
  class file for io.restassured.common.mapper.TypeRef not found
```

It was exactly in this place:

```
    @Test
    public void callOAuth2ProtectedApi() throws JSONException {
        String accessToken = getAccessTokenFromOAuth2();
        Student request = new Student(1l, "Elon Musk", "elonmusk@gmail.com", "pccoe");

        Student response = RestAssured.given()
                .auth()
                .oauth2(accessToken)
                .baseUri("http://localhost:8088")
                .pathParam("student_rollNumber", "2")
                .body(request)
                .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
                .when()
                .get("/students/{student_rollNumber}")
                .then()
                .extract()
                .as(Student.class);   -- here
        System.out.println("Student api Response - " + response);
        Assert.assertEquals(response, request);
    }
```

does anybody now why such error appeared?
I changed such things in pom.xml:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.2</version>   -- newest version
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

I added:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-impl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

I try to run this on Microsoft\jdk-11.0.16.101-hotspot.

BR,
fotrenc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to solve it in a short way:

- run application under java 1.8.
- add only in maven new version of rest-assured dependency

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.2</version>   -- newest version
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Now it will be possible to run application and tests with Rest-assured requests.